# How to make sure an HTML element is in the center of the window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, window

I want to execute a function on one element in the center of the window, and another function when leaving the element in the center. So how to make sure the HTML element is in the center of the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Use following style attributes:*

> ```
> display: table-cell;
> vertical-align:middle;
> text-align:center;
> height:100%;
> width:100%;
> ```

*Hope this solves!*

Comment: sorry this not the correct one....
make sure it... while scroling html page.... have some 5 elements.... while scrolling first element getting center at the time i have to perform some action... five some code for that